# Can't get HTML from Ajax or Append response to DIV - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get a simple response from a controller and append it to a `div` so I can see the output on the front end.  Here is my JQuery:

```
 $('.js-mapsearch').keyup(function (e) {

            var characters = $(this);
            var $output = $('.js-output');

            console.log(characters.val() + ' was pressed');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/umbraco/surface/MapSearchSurface/GetPlaces?Characters=' + characters,
                datatype: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/text',
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data) {
                        $output.append($(data).html());
                        console.log($(data).html());
                        console.log(data);
                    }

                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    console.log(ex);
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();



});
```

Here are the `console.log`:

```
console.log($(data).html());  // [object Object]
console.log(data);            // <div class="js-places-container">[object Object]</div>
```

Here is the `razor` code:

```
@model Prodo.umbraco.Web.Models.GetPlacesModel

<div class="js-places-container">@Model.Places</div>
```

Here is my `controller` code:

```
public ActionResult GetPlaces(string Characters)
        {
            var Model = new GetPlacesModel();

            Model.Places = Characters;

            return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/_MapSearchResults.cshtml", Model);
        }
```

And `model` code:

```
public class GetPlacesModel
    {
        public string Places { get; set; }
    }
```

In theory, I should for now be able to see which characters are being typed in on the front end via the `$('.js-output')` `div`.  Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code is working exactly how you are telling it to, you are just passing in the string `[object Object]` in your javascript.

this sets it to an object

```
var characters = $(this);
```

and when you use it

```
url: '/umbraco/surface/MapSearchSurface/GetPlaces?Characters=' + characters
```

it calls the default `.toString()` method of the `characters` object.

What you want to actually do is set it like this:

```
var characters = $(this).val();
```

Or something similar for whatever is appropriate to get the string value you want to pass on.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes sense now.  However, I am getting each character typed to log as it should now, but sadly I still cant seem to get the element `$('.js-output')` that has been appended `append('<p>' + $(data).html() + '</p>');` to show on the front end.

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, and we'd need to see your html as well to get an idea of why that might not be showing up.

Comment: Thanks Matti, the issue in the html code was the class name was incorrect so all is good. I’ll mark this as an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$.get('your/url/template.html').done(function (data) {
       $('#your_div').append(data);
});
```